# Building documentation into software

Tags: user-interface, documentation, user-experience

I have seen several applications that explain features to the user when they first use it or bring new features to their attention after an upgrade. This kind of documentation appears directly within the app and in the midst of the user's flow, e.g. by laying a speech bubble over the UI which points to the button or any other element. Usually it appears once and never again.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to call this approach, which makes it hard to even google about it. It seems to be a quite modern UX approach.

I am wondering what architectural or design patterns are used or whether there are any notable libraries to implement that. The issue I am trying to address is that this is a cross-cutting thing which creeps into any place and any time in the work flows - and yet you want to keep this whole concern out of the "actual" functionality.

For example, the user might request a page in an MVC webapp. The controller fetches data, executes actions and serves a view. On that view is a new tab. The user has not ever seen this and you want to display a friendly message "click here to...". This means that in some place, probably in the controller, you must detect that this feature has not been explained to the user yet - you load a message from a bundle and send it to the view. The view renders a speech bubble in addition to the tab. This logic has nothing to do with the actual functionality. Ideally you can keep it out of the controller as well as the view.

I was thinking whether an Aspect-Oriented-Programming approach could help.

Is there any blog, library, established patterns?

**Please note: I am not asking how to render a speech bubble. My concern is that I don't want the logic - to decide when to display it ("has the user ever seen the message? Have they picked "don't show again?"), what to display, and where to display it - to be spread across the whole application source code. Ideally it could be packed into its own package or project.**

Similar considerations can apply for collecting feature usage statistics or for adding a user feedback channel in various places.

**Update:** I finally got an answer point to exactly what I was looking for. Since finding a term for it was the main issue, I am adding some of the keywords found in Shahrokh's answer so as to help future readers find this Q&A: This thing can be called an introduction, step-by-step guide, page guide, or a guided website tour for first-time users; the answer features intro.js, aSimpleTourPlugin, pageguide.js, joyride, Codrops, Bootstro.js, jQuery SiteTour, jQuery Tourbus, Trip.js, and Crumble.

Comment: I think they call that (or something like that) a context menu in Win32/Windows.

Comment: @PeterL. not even close. A context menu is when you right-click on something.

Comment: This is probably off-topic, and better suited for http://ux.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Jonathon: Maybe I was unclear? I was asking about the programming concerns of this, not about the UX: "what architectural or design patterns are used or whether there are any notable libraries"

Comment: @Jonathon: I tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @joran: Any way you could explain me why this is off-topic? I've been around on Stackoverflow for >4 years and have read the FAQ several times, last time right now - but this is a fully programming-related question. It seems that I did not manage to be clear enough in formulation, maybe a comment could help me improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of **Web Page User Guide** or **Website Tour** for your web page is [here](http://www.w3update.com/resource/awesome-jquery-plugins-to-let-you-create-web-page-user-guide.html).

Comment: Wow! I gave up on this but this is exactly what I was looking for! I'd vote up 10x for the 10 different links that hide behind your reference :-)

Comment: My suggestion for website tour is "introjs", because it's simple, light and have a good community.

Comment: Thank you. I've had a glance at all links (out of which were still working), and introjs was the one I had the best impression of so far.

Comment: stackoverflow help: http://stackoverflow.com/tour :-)

Comment: Very nice, too - however this is a separate help page, not an "inline" tour. The help texts are part of the content, they simply animate them a little.